# Extremely slow backoffice

Tags: php, performance, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have recently updated my prestashop to 1.6, and since then, I'm experiencing performance issues.
I have activated error messages in order to check if everything was ok and I found some messages telling me the following:

```
Notice on line 1279 en archivo /var/www/vhosts/vallesonline.es/httpdocs/modules/inixframe/InixModule.php
[8] Undefined property: stdClass::$dist_chanel

Notice on line 1280 en archivo /var/www/vhosts/vallesonline.es/httpdocs/modules/inixframe/InixModule.php
[8] Undefined property: stdClass::$dist_chanel
```

The lines 1279 and 1280 are the author and dist_chanel ones:

```
$module_data = array(
'name'=> $module->name,
'version'=> $module->version,
'author'=>$module->dist_chanel,
'dist_chanel'=> $module->dist_chanel,
);
```

It is evident that there is some problem with some modules that do not have dist_chanel property, so I check if the module has it or not in order to bypass the problem. If the var is not defined, I set author and diet_channel to ''.

Then, at the end of my log file I found the following:

```
Notice on line 1957 en archivo /var/www/vhosts/vallesonline.es/httpdocs/classes/Tools.php
[8] Array to string conversion
```

The line is the following:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

In which post_data contains the data created on InixModule.php (the var module_data).

I think this problem is causing the performance issues on my prestashop and that has something to do with the update (which I did using 1-click-update).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably you need to update some module to the current version. Googling for inixframe appear some results related to one module called Affiliate Plus Program from www.presta-apps.com

Comment: I think you should report your errors here  http://forge.prestashop.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa , I did it and prestashop experts helped me out. I also had errors on updating prestashop and my back office was slow. They may take a few days to respond though.

Comment: I will repot it on [forge.prestashop.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa](http://forge.prestashop.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa). I'll post here the solution (if any). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had same error message. My solution is uninstalling module named "Presta Apps Dashboard" developed by InixFrame.
Solved till now.

Answer (score -1):

Do a chmod -R 774 to /var/www/html/prestashop/config/xml/ if you have different users for both owner and group.

Or chown (change ownership) of /var/www/html/prestashop/config/xml/*.xml to www-data:www-data or apache2:apache2 depending on Debian/Ubuntu or Redhat/CentOS - that might help, it might be just permission issue if you check on apache's error log.

The next thing should be just some tweaking on Smarty under Performance to cache all stuffs.